# Doubt on an identity vs equation intuition

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, 3d

u+v+w=0  (1)
-u+v+w=0   (2)
Adding (1) and (2) we have
2v+2w=0
or, v=-w   (3)
Substituting (3) in (1) we have 
u=0    (4)
y the place where they substituted v=-w in equation (1) while applying the Weiss Zone law is it permissible?I am asking this because I have used those two equations only to arrive at v=-w.Is this not an identity type of approach instead of an equation type?

Comment: Can you post the whole system please?

Comment: There is nothing more other than the two equations.@Dr.SonnhardGraubner. Equation (1) and (2) are the only two equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding both equations we get
$$v=-w$$, plugging this in one of the equations above we get
$u-w+w=0$ so $u=0$ and we get
$$[u,v,w]=[0,-w,w]$$

Comment: Yes correct but what allows me to substitute v=-w in the equation u-v+w=0 where I have derived v=-w relation from using the same u-v+w=0.Is this not going to be some of those 5=5 or 6=6 situation?